# Delphi FMX: How to create a string grid cell with multiple columns

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have a string grid, but I want to create cells that would be split into 3 "mini" columns within the cell, how would I do this, if it is possible, using FMX delphi?

So essentially in the grid each cell would have 3 columns (1 row), and in each of those columns is a cell.

This string grid would be to represent a calendar/diary planner etc, each of the main cells would be a day in the month, and the mini cells would represent an early/late/night time frame in the day. What I would like to have is the ability to access `TStringGrid.Cells[x,y]` and then set the columns within that Cell to a certain letter/number. So the cell would be shown as e.g 24 E L N, the 24 if possible could be a header to the main cell.

Comment: So why can you not simply triple the number of columns. Or, how do you envisage to address each "mini" column? Do you store the strings in your own data structure, what does it look like? You need to be more specific and elaborate your question with more detail. Please edit your question.

Comment: @TomBrunberg hi tom, i've edited the question please let me know if that's suitable